# Laravel many to many grab only one value from relation

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have a many to many relation between `Expense` and `Tag`. Now I want to grab only the `name` from all tags that are related to an `Expense`.

So, let's say I have an `Expense`:

```
$expense = Expense::first();
```

And now I can grab all tags easily:

```
$tags = $expense->tags;
```

This will give me a collection of Tags. Ideally, I want to have an array of the tag names:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "tag1"
  1 => " tag2"
  2 => " tag3"
  3 => " tag4"
  4 => " tag5"
]
```

Now I can accomplish that by doing this:

```
$tags = $expense->tags;

$new_tags = [];

foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    $new_tags[] = $tag->name;
}
```

But is there a cleaner way, especially without having to use `foreach`? I tried something like this:

```
$tags = $expense->tags->value('name')->toArray();

$tags = $expense->tags()->value('name')->toArray();
```

But both aren't working. Is there a way to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$tags = $expense->tags->pluck('name')->toArray();
```

or

```
$tags = $expense->tags->pluck('name')->all();
```

Comment: I even knew about pluck .. Thanks, totally forgot about it :)

Comment: I glade help you

Answer (score 3):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
$tags = $expense->tags->pluck('name');
```

You can further read over here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck

Comment: My pleasure my friend :)